# I can't install Realm Object Server

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, realm

I'm currently creating my first application using Realm Mobile Platfrom ,
My objectif is to do a real-time Sync App using Javascript .
when i tried to install the Realm Object Server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bits following the instructions in their official site i had this problem : 
E: Unable to locate package realm-object-server-developer .
 I think the problem is when i do this command : 
"curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/realm/realm/script.deb.sh | sudo bash "  nothing happens , but normally an installation should start? 
I can't find a way to fix this problem and i'll be grateful if someone can help me .

Comment: Can you include link to documentation at Question? You might need to set permission of file as executable, place `.sh` file in `PATH`, then run the file at `terminal`.

Comment: this is the documentation you asked about :
https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/ 
 i am going to try your solution and give you feeback :)

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at link? You need to run `$ sudo apt-get update` and the commands that follow after running `curl`

Comment: when i do this command : 
''sudo apt-get install realm-object-server-developer  ''  
i get this error : 
E : unable to locate package realm-object-server-developer

Comment: Do you follow the instructions at "Ubunto 16.04" in exact order?

Comment: Yes Ofcourse , i installed many other servers before and never had this problem .

Comment: Will try, to determine if have same issue. You are correct. Same issue. Consider notifying maintainers of package while try to determine what issue is.

Comment: You can get the `.deb` at https://packagecloud.io/realm/realm/. Apparently  `apt` needs to be run at `https:` protocol

Comment: Followed instructions at https://packagecloud.io/realm/realm/install#manual, same result. At bottom of page: _"If you're looking for further clarification on anything, don't hesitate to get in touch!"_ with link to email contact.

Comment: Even the link to '' Get in touch '' doesnt work :(  
I am going to try some few things before i give up on this one ...

Comment: It would appear PackageCloud is having some issues. We're not quite sure why this is the case. We're seeing it in our CI system as well, and some people have reported it on our public issue tracker. We've opened an issue with PackageCloud, but they need some extra information. They've asked for some extra information to help out: Could you email us your external IP address and the approximate timestamp at which this occured? You can reach me at help@realm.io. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmedSelmi: The "Get in touch" link on that page works for me though. Do you have an email client configured on your computer? It's just a regular `mailto` link.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , yes the link worked fine for me too after Rebooting , i will try to add more information about this error in github as requested .

Answer (score 0):

I found some answers that might help:

1-The contact link redirects you to this mail address: support@packagecloud.io

2-there is also a similar problem in this link :)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt

Good luck Bro <3

Answer (score 0):

I've responded to your support email and I am further debugging the issue over at the realm github repository: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/9

Any additional information you can provide will be much appreciated. Feel free to close this post, as we'll be updating the github issue thread with any new developments. Thanks.